# Check sub element of an Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to check the 2nd level deep of array element and i tried .intersect  and map seems i am not doing it well. My code look like this 
Icon is an object with element inside URL and i want to make sure that this URL is not empty with the below filter.

```
response.RelatedTopics.filter(function (el) {
  return el.Icon !== '' && el.URL !== '' && el.Text !== '';
```

})

But when i add to element of  Icon which is this uRL i usually get error and this is the condition i want to cheeck below.

```
el.Icon.URL !== ''

But when i add .URL i am getting error. Someone help pls.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`return el.Icon && el.Icon.URL && el.Text`

Comment: Thanks it worked there was a typo in my code earlier on!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Mumin Korcan worked but i finally constructed it like this. and i got what i wanted no difference though! Thanks Mumin Korcan

return el.Icon && el.Icon.URL && el.Text !== '';